# select specific column Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pagination

I want to change below controller to that can select from two column (id , number)

```
public function invalidcustomersAction()
    {
        $smsModel = new Model_SimInCust(); 
        $select = $smsModel->select();
        $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select));
        $paginator ->setItemCountPerPage(5)
        ->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page',1));
        $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
    }
```

I already have this in my model

```
<?php
class Model_SimInCust extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'invalid';
    protected $_schema  = 'invalid_sim';

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your **select** to this :

```
$select = $smsModel->select()->from($smsModel, array('id','number'));
```